# Boost ASIO async_read is not reading data from the server

Tags: c++, boost

I have a server/client application which works for a write from client to a read at server.

After the sever is done receiving the data in the function read_async_1, it writes a simple string "Response" at the end.

Now, this is not received at the client. In the client code, **StartHandlingServer** is what does an async read.. ***Now, the handler inside this is not getting called..***

Can someone please have a look at this ? Appreciate your feedback.

**Server Code**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "../stocks.hpp"
using namespace boost;


class Service {
public:
    Service(){}

    void StartHandligClient(boost::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock)
    {
        std::cout << "StartHandligClient : sock.use_count : " << sock.use_count() << "\n";
        read_async_1(sock);
        return;

    }

private:
    void read_async_1(boost::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock)
    {
        if(!(*sock.get()).is_open())
        {
            std::cout << getpid() << " : Socket closed in sync_read \n" << std::flush;
            return ;
        }

        std::cout << "haha_1\n" << std::flush;

        boost::asio::async_read( (*sock.get()), boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_),
                [this, sock](boost::system::error_code ec,
                    size_t bytesRead)
                {
                int headerBytesReceived = bytesRead;
                std::cout << "\n\n headerBytesReceived : " << headerBytesReceived << "\n" << std::flush ;

                if (!ec)
                {

                // Determine the length of the serialized data.
                std::istringstream is(std::string(inbound_header_, header_length));
                std::cout << "is : +" << is.str() << "+, inbound_header_ : +" << inbound_header_ << "+\n";

                std::size_t inbound_data_size = 0;
                if (!(is >> std::hex >> inbound_data_size))
                {
                // Header doesn't seem to be valid. Inform the caller.
                // boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
                // boost::get<0>(handler)(error);
                    std::cout << "RET-1 \n";
                    return;
                }

                std::cout << "inbound_data_size : " << inbound_data_size << "\n" << std::flush;

                // Start an asynchronous call to receive the data.
                inbound_data_.resize(inbound_data_size);

                std::cout << "inbound_data_.size() : " << inbound_data_.size() << "\n" << std::flush;

                int bytesReceived = asio::read( *sock.get(), boost::asio::buffer(inbound_data_) );

                std::string archive_data(&inbound_data_[0], inbound_data_.size());
                std::istringstream archive_stream(archive_data);
                boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
                archive >> stocks_;


                std::cout << "bytesReceived : " << bytesReceived << " , stocks_.size() : " << stocks_.size() << "\n";
                // Print out the data that was received.
                for (std::size_t i = 0; i < stocks_.size(); ++i)
                {
                    std::cout << "Stock number " << i << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  code: " << stocks_[i].code << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  name: " << stocks_[i].name << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  open_price: " << stocks_[i].open_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  high_price: " << stocks_[i].high_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  low_price: " << stocks_[i].low_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  last_price: " << stocks_[i].last_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  buy_price: " << stocks_[i].buy_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  buy_quantity: " << stocks_[i].buy_quantity << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  sell_price: " << stocks_[i].sell_price << "\n";
                    std::cout << "  sell_quantity: " << stocks_[i].sell_quantity << "\n";
                }            

                sleep(1);
                // Sending response.
                std::string response = "Response\n";
                asio::write(*sock.get(), asio::buffer(response));


                this->read_async_1(sock);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Terminate connection ?
                    if(ec == boost::asio::error::eof)
                    {
                            std::cout << getpid() << " : ** sync_read : Connection lost  : boost::asio::error::eof ** \n";
                    }
                        std::cout << "Error occured in async_read! Error code = " << ec.value() << ". Message: " << ec.message() << "\n" << std::flush;

                    return ;
                }
                return ;
                }
        );
        std::cout << getpid() << " : final return from async_read \n" << std::flush;
        return ;
    }
/// The size of a fixed length header.
enum { header_length = 8 };

/// Holds an outbound header.
std::string outbound_header_;

/// Holds the outbound data.
std::string outbound_data_;

/// Holds an inbound header.
char inbound_header_[header_length];

/// Holds the inbound data.
std::vector<char> inbound_data_;
    std::vector<stock> stocks_;
};

class Acceptor {
public:
    Acceptor(asio::io_service& ios, unsigned short port_num) :
        m_ios(ios),
        m_acceptor(m_ios,
        asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
        asio::ip::address_v4::any(),
        port_num))
    {
        m_acceptor.listen();
    }

    void Accept() {
        std::cout << "Server Accept() \n" << std::flush;
        boost::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock(new asio::ip::tcp::socket(m_ios));

        m_acceptor.accept(*sock.get());

        (new Service)->StartHandligClient(sock);

        std::cout << "Accept : sock.use_count : " << sock.use_count() << "\n";
    }

private:
    asio::io_service& m_ios;
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
};

class Server {
public:
    Server() : m_stop(false) {}

    void Start(unsigned short port_num) {
        m_thread.reset(new std::thread([this, port_num]() {
            Run(port_num);
        }));
    }

    void Stop() {
        std::cout << "STOPPING \n";
        m_stop.store(true);
        m_thread->join();
    }

private:
    void Run(unsigned short port_num) {
        Acceptor acc(m_ios, port_num);

        while (!m_stop.load())
        {
            std::cout << "Server accept\n" << std::flush;
            acc.Accept();

            m_ios.run();
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_thread;
    std::atomic<bool> m_stop;
    asio::io_service m_ios;
};

int main()
{
    unsigned short port_num = 3333;

    try {
        Server srv;
        srv.Start(port_num);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));

        std::cout << "Stopping server \n";

        srv.Stop();
    }
    catch (system::system_error &e) {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = "
            << e.code() << ". Message: "
            << e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client Code**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include "../stocks.hpp"
using namespace boost;

class mysock : public boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
{
    public:
        mysock(asio::io_service& serv) : boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(serv)
    {
    }
        ~mysock()
        {
            std::cout << "Inside destructor for mysock \n";
        }
};

class SyncTCPClient {
public:
    SyncTCPClient(const std::string& raw_ip_address,
        unsigned short port_num) :
        socket_((new mysock(m_ios))),
        m_ep(asio::ip::address::from_string(raw_ip_address), port_num)

    {
        (*socket_.get()).open(m_ep.protocol());

        connect();

        StartHandlingServer(socket_);

    }
    mysock& socket()
    {
        return *socket_.get();
    }

    void connect() {
        (*socket_.get()).connect(m_ep);
        m_ios.run();
    }

    void StartHandlingServer(boost::shared_ptr<mysock>  sock)
    {
        if(!(*sock.get()).is_open())
        {
            std::cout << getpid() << " : Socket closed in sync_read \n" << std::flush;
            return ;
        }

        std::cout << "Start StartHandlingServer\n" << std::flush;

        char inbound_header_[4];;
        try
        {
        boost::asio::async_read( (*sock.get()), boost::asio::buffer(inbound_header_),
                [this, sock](boost::system::error_code ec,
                    size_t bytesRead)
                {
                int headerBytesReceived = bytesRead;
                std::cout << "\n\n headerBytesReceived : " << headerBytesReceived << "\n" << std::flush ;

                if (!ec)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    if(ec == boost::asio::error::eof)
                    {
                            std::cout << getpid() << " : ** sync_read : Connection lost  : boost::asio::error::eof ** \n";
                    }
                        std::cout << "Error occured in async_read! Error code = " << ec.value() << ". Message: " << ec.message() << "\n" << std::flush;

                    return ;
                }

                }
                );
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Done StartHandlingServer\n" << std::flush;
    }

    void close() {
        (*socket_.get()).shutdown(
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
        (*socket_.get()).close();
    }

    std::string emulateLongComputationOp(
        unsigned int duration_sec) {

        std::string request = "EMULATE_LONG_COMP_OP "
            + std::to_string(duration_sec)
            + "\n";

        sendRequest(request);

        /*
        sleep(2);
        sendRequest(request);

        sleep(2);
        sendRequest(request);
        */

        return receiveResponse();
    };

private:
    void sendRequest(const std::string& request) {

        std::vector<stock> stocks_;
        // Create the data to be sent to each client.
        stock s;
        s.code = "ABC";
        s.name = "A Big Company";
        s.open_price = 4.56;
        s.high_price = 5.12;
        s.low_price = 4.33;
        s.last_price = 4.98;
        s.buy_price = 4.96;
        s.buy_quantity = 1000;
        s.sell_price = 4.99;
        s.sell_quantity = 2000;
        stocks_.push_back(s);

        // Serialize the data first so we know how large it is.
        std::ostringstream archive_stream;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive << stocks_;
        outbound_data_ = archive_stream.str();
        std::cout << "outbound_data_ : " << outbound_data_ << "\n" << std::flush;
        std::cout << "outbound_data_.size() : " << outbound_data_.size() << "\n" << std::flush;

        // Format the header.
        std::ostringstream header_stream;
        header_stream << std::setw(header_length)  << std::hex << outbound_data_.size();

        std::cout << "header_stream.str() : " << header_stream.str() << "\n" << std::flush;
        std::cout << "header_stream.str().size() : " << header_stream.str().size() << "\n" << std::flush;

        if (!header_stream || header_stream.str().size() != header_length)
        {
            // Something went wrong, inform the caller.
            // boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
            // socket_.get_io_service().post(boost::bind(handler, error));
            return;
        }

        outbound_header_ = header_stream.str();
        std::cout << "outbound_header_ : +" << outbound_header_ << "+\n" << std::flush;

        // Write the serialized data to the socket. We use "gather-write" to send
        // both the header and the data in a single write operation.
        /*
        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
        buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
        buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
        */

        std::size_t headerSize = asio::write(*socket_.get(), boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
        std::size_t dataSize   = asio::write(*socket_.get(), boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
        std::cout << "headerSize : " << headerSize << " , dataSize : " << dataSize;

    }

    std::string receiveResponse() {
        std::string response;
        /*
        asio::streambuf buf;
        asio::read_until(*socket_.get(), buf, '\n');

        std::istream input(&buf);

        std::getline(input, response);
        */

        return response;
    }

private:
    asio::io_service m_ios;
    boost::shared_ptr<mysock> socket_;

    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint m_ep;
    enum { header_length = 8 };
    std::string outbound_data_;
    std::string outbound_header_;

};

int main()
{
    const std::string raw_ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    const unsigned short port_num = 3333;

    try {
        SyncTCPClient client(raw_ip_address, port_num);

        std::cout << "Sending request to the server... \n"<< std::endl;

        std::string response = client.emulateLongComputationOp(10);

        std::cout << "\nResponse received: " << response << std::endl;

        sleep(10);
        std::cout << "\n\n Closing client connection \n\n";

        // Close the connection and free resources.
        client.close();
    }
    catch (system::system_error &e) {
        std::cout << "Client Error occured! Error code = " << e.code()
            << ". Message: " << e.what();

        return e.code().value();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Included file stocks.hpp**

```
#ifndef _STOCKS_HPP_
#define _STOCKS_HPP_

struct stock
{
  std::string code;
  std::string name;
  double open_price;
  double high_price;
  double low_price;
  double last_price;
  double buy_price;
  int buy_quantity;
  double sell_price;
  int sell_quantity;

  template <typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & code;
    ar & name;
    ar & open_price;
    ar & high_price;
    ar & low_price;
    ar & last_price;
    ar & buy_price;
    ar & buy_quantity;
    ar & sell_price;
    ar & sell_quantity;
  }
};

#endif
```

Comment: @rafix07 : I did check completely things based on your feedbacks in the post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128834/boost-asio-async-read-is-not-reading-data-from-the-client . But, I am not able to get an idea... Request you to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The [`io_service::run`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html) function runs until there are no more events.

In the client you run it once, when there are no active events to be handled, which means it will return immediately.

Because the `io_server` isn't "running" it will not handle any events.

You need to call `run` (or `poll`) in a loop, like you do in the server.

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer .. So, what & which is the best place to ensure that the run continues ?

Comment: @NishantSharma That depends. I usually use a thread which calls `run` in a loop while the `io_service` isn't stopped.

Comment: Okay... So, I have to use the same instance of io_service everywhere in the code... I mean there cannot be two different instances and I do not run the one on which socket is opened....